# How to use the !! expression?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

I find the js code write like this ： !!undefined , !!false;

the jquery source code (jQuery 1.7.0.js: Line 748):

```
grep: function( elems, callback, inv ) {       
    var ret = [], retVal;        
    inv = !!inv;         
    // Go through the array, only saving the items       
    // that pass the validator function        
    for ( var i = 0, length = elems.length; i < length; i++ ){              
        retVal = !!callback( elems[ i ], i );            
        if ( inv !== retVal ) {                
            ret.push( elems[ i ] );            
        }        
    }         
    return ret;    
}
```

Comment: Well, that does `!expr` do? What does `!(!expr)` do? Put the little parts together into a bigger part :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript), more specifically [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`!` means `opposite`

So `!!` means `double opposite`.

It is also commonly used in this case:

```
var check = !!(window.something && window.runthis)
//If something exists and runthis exists, then
//check = true

//If one of them is not exist, then
//check = false
```

Commonly used in [checking browser compatibly](http://www.modernizr.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It's a shorthand way of casting a non-boolean object to a boolean.

For example, !!0 would convert to false.

Answer (score 0):

its simply double negation used to coerce any data type (null, undefined, objects) to boolean

http://navirudra.com/blog/javascript/javascript-double-negative-trick.html